# can anybody help me to solve this pointer question in c

Tags: c, pointers, constants

can anybody help me understand this code (in c)..

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

   const int a =5;int b;

   int *p;

   p= (int *) &a;



  b=a;



   *p= *p +1;

   printf(" value of p is = %d\n", *p);  

   printf(" value of b is = %d\n", b);

   printf(" value of a is = %d\n",a);

}
```

result is

: value of p is = 6

: value of b is = 5

: value of a is = 6

Comment: This code is wrong because it modifies a `const` variable. It may give other results than shown here or even crash.

Comment: @interjay explain this https://ideone.com/3wfWlL

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Undefined behavior means that anything can happen, which is why you got a different result than OP.

Comment: Hmm so it means anything can happen  cool

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan: Technically, undefined behavior means that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.  The actual result can depend on the platform, the compiler, any optimization flags, the surrounding code, the runtime environment, etc., and it's not guaranteed to be repeatable or predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the instruction `p = (int *)&a;` you made `p` to point at `a`.
As a result expression `*p` refers to the variable `a`, hence `*p = *p + 1;` worked as equivalent to `a = a + 1;` – variable `a` got assigned its previous value (which was 5) incremented by 1.
So it's finally 6.

This, however, is an Undefined Behavior, as @interjay points out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923471/can-anybody-help-me-to-solve-this-pointer-question-in-c/67923585?noredirect=1#comment120056050_67923585) – the `a` variable is declared as `const`, which means it must not be modified. As a result the compiler might choose to allocate it in a read-only area of memory. It did not in your case, and an assignment succeeded, but in other case the modfication of the variable might silently fail (with `a` value remaining 5) or yield a memory access exception (and terminate the program) or whatever.

Comment: Note that `a` is `const` so modifying it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @interjay But the value got incremented, didn't it? So the assignment through the pointer worked as it could do directly. Of course, as an UB, it might have failed or do anything else, but in this case it resulted equivalently to a direct assignment to a (non-const) variable.

Comment: UB can be anything, including the intended result. But it cannot be relied upon and suggesting otherwise is wrong. When I tested OP's code I got a different result.

Comment: @interjay You're right. I have expanded my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Before the explanation, let me tell you that this is part is a bit problematic, and can lead to undefined behavior:

```
const int a =5;
p= (int *) &a;
```

You should remove `const`, because in this case you want to modify the contents of `a` through pointers. Some compilers (such as clang, as someone mentioned in the comments) might perform optimizations, like replacing where the const variable is used with its value, to reduce the number of memory access operations.

---

Let's imagine that each variable is a little box where you can put numbers. So you have 3 boxes:

```
+---+   +---+   +---+
| 5 |   |   |   |   |
+---+   +---+   +---+
  a       b       p
```

Now let's go over each statement and see what is happening.

```
   int *p;

   p= (int *) &a;
```

`p` is defined as a pointer, which is a type of variable that can hold the address of something in memory. In this case, it is assigned the address of variable `a`. So our boxes now look like this:

```
  +---------------+
  v               |
+---+   +---+   +----+
| 5 |   |   |   | &a |
+---+   +---+   +----+
  a       b       p
```

`p` simply contains the memory address of `a`. You can print it with `printf("%u", a)`, and you will see some number. That is the address of `a`.

```
  b=a;
```

Here we are copying the value of `a` into `b`, so our boxes become:

```
  +---------------+
  v               |
+---+   +---+   +----+
| 5 |   | 5 |   | &a |
+---+   +---+   +----+
  a       b       p
```

---

```
   *p= *p +1;
```

Using the `*p` syntax, we can dereference the pointer, that means that we can access the memory that `p` is pointing to (follow the arrow). In this case, `*p` will allow us to get or set the contents of the `a` variable. Our boxes now become like this:

```
  +---------------+
  v               |
+---+   +---+   +----+
| 6 |   | 5 |   | &a |
+---+   +---+   +----+
  a       b       p
```

---

```
   printf(" value of p is = %d\n", *p);
```

Here you are again dereferencing p, meaning that we are getting the contents of the memory at address `p`. In our case, this will get the contents of the `a` variable which is `6`.

```
   printf(" value of b is = %d\n", b);
```

Looking at the `b` box, we can see that it contains `5`.

```
   printf(" value of a is = %d\n",a);
```

We modified `a` using the pointer. Looking at the `a` box, we can see that it contains the value `6`.

Comment: Good explanation of pointers. However, note that `a` is `const` so modifying it is undefined behavior. When I run this with clang, `a` still contains the value 5.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of this code is to update the value of `a` through the pointer `p`.  Let's strip away some things and start with the basics:

```
int a = 5; 
int *p = &a;
```

We have an object named `a` that stores the integer value `5`.  We have another object named `p` that stores the *address* of `a`.  After the two declarations above, the following conditions are true:

```
 p == &a  == some address value 
*p ==  a  == 5
```

The *expression* `*p` is equivalent to the expression `a` - assigning a new value to `*p` is the same as assigning a new value to `a`, so

```
*p = *p + 1
```

is the same as writing

```
a = a + 1
```

However, in the code you posted `a` has been declared as a `const int`.  That means you are telling the compiler that the value of `a` is not supposed to change over its lifetime.  The compiler will flag any statement like

```
a = a + 1
```

or

```
a++;
```

as an error.  The compiler *may* also store `a` in read-only memory; if you never take the address of `a` (that is, if it's never the operand of unary `&`), the compiler *may* not reserve any storage for it *at all* and just replace any instance of it with the value (IOW, anywhere you would expect to see a reference to `a` in the machine code you would just see a literal `5`), meaning there's nothing to write to at all.

But this code *cheats* - it declares `p` as a pointer to a *non*-`const` `int`.  The type of the *expression* `&a` is `const int *` (pointer to `const int`), but the type of `p` is just `int *` (pointer to `int`).  In the assignment

```
p = (int *) &a;
```

you are *casting away* the `const` qualifier on `a`.  So when you write a new value to `*p`, the compiler *doesn't know* that you're trying to modify something that was declared as `const` so it won't flag it as an error.

The C language definition says that trying to update a `const`-qualified object through a non-`const`-qualified lvalue<sup>1</sup> results in *undefined behavior* - the compiler is not required to handle the situation in any particular way.  The result can be any one of:

- a runtime error;
- the value of `a` remaining unchanged;
- behaving exactly as expected;

or something else entirely.

---

1. An lvalue is any expression that designates an object such that the object my be read or modified.  Both `a` and `*p` are lvalues that refer to an integer object containing the value `5`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is entirely in the following line:

```
p= (int *) &a;
```

Without the type cast, the line would read:

```
p = &a;
```

The type of `a` is `const int`.
The type of `p` is `int *`.

It is obvious that the compiler should warn about discarding the `const` qualifier:

> warning: assigning to 'int *' from 'const int *' discards qualifiers
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]

This demonstrates why you should always try to avoid explicit type casting (unless strictly necessary). The author of this code shot themselves in the foot. They introduced undefined behaviour and the obvious problem was hidden, because the warning was discarded or suppressed